# Using First() with a generic collection through reflection

Tags: c#, generics

Assume a method declared as the following:

```
public static string GetString<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, string theProperty)
```

How can I, using reflection, return the value of property theProperty of the first element in the generic collection? (using Linq's First() method).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error checking omitted for brevity:

```
return (string) typeof(T).GetProperty(theProperty).GetValue(collection.First(), null);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public static string GetString<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, string theProperty)
{
  return (string)(typeof(T)).GetProperty(theProperty).GetValue(collection.First(), null));
}
```